# Eclipse Plugin: FileStoreEditorInput access unsaved data

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm trying to access a file's data that is not part of the workspace and after some testing found out my objects is of type FileStoreEditorInput. The solutions I found to accessing FileStoreEditorInput's data made use of normal Java concept which should not have access to unsaved data inside the Eclipse environment.

For files that are opened inside the workspace I got it to work with FileEditorInput and the following (convoluted) code:

```
private static IEditorReference[] ii;

private static String isOpenInEclipse(String path){
    Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ii = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getEditorReferences();
        }
    });

    for(IEditorReference ier : ii){
        // Fetch the editor's page
        try {
            IEditorInput iei = ier.getEditorInput();
            if(iei instanceof FileEditorInput){
                IFile file = ((FileEditorInput)iei).getFile();
                IEditorPart p;
                // If the editor got the same path and is a text editor, return its data
                if(path.contains(file.getRawLocation().toOSString()) && 
                        (p = ier.getEditor(false)) instanceof ITextEditor){
                    IDocumentProvider provider = ((ITextEditor)p).getDocumentProvider();
                    IDocument document = provider.getDocument(p.getEditorInput());
                    return document.get();
                }
            }
        } catch (PartInitException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Is there a similar solution for FileStoreEditorInput so I can just add on the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileStoreEditorInput` implements `IURIEditorInput` so you can get a `File` object using something like:

```
if (editorInput instanceof IURIEditorInput)
 {
   IURIEditorInput uriInput = (IURIEditorInput)editorInput;

   URI uri = uriInput.getURI();

   File file = new File(uri);

   ... test path

   .. get document contents in the same way
 }
```

Comment: Since it's a file object won't it only be able to read what's saved inside the document? I want access to unsaved data.

Comment: You can use the document provider and document in exactly the same way to get the editor document contents.

Comment: Ohh. Okay. Accepted the answer.